# pl/sql - Using a dynamic query inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using a stored procedure to insert data into a temp table using a cursor.
This procedure stores a dynamic query inside a variable to mount the insert/update command.

Here is the code(not the full query, I've cut some parts to make it easier to read):

```
 FOR VC2 IN (SELECT C.OBJETIVO,
                C.AUDITORIA ,
                C.NOME, 
                C.PRODUTO
           FROM CALCULO C)
  LOOP

  SELECT  ' V_UPD NUMBER := 0;

              SELECT (SELECT ID_TIPO_TERR  
              FROM ZREPORTYTD_TMP 
             WHERE AUDITORIA = ''' || VC2.AUDITORIA || '''
                AND TERRITORIO = ''' || VC2.NOME  || '''
                AND PRODUTO = ''' || VC2.PRODUTO || ''') 
               INTO V_UPD FROM DUAL;

                  UPDATE ZReportYTD_TMP
                     SET  TARGET = ' || VC2.OBJETIVO  || '
                   WHERE AUDITORIA = ''' || VC2.AUDITORIA || '''
                     AND TERRITORIO = ''' || VC2.NOME  || '''
                     AND PRODUTO = ''' || VC2.PRODUTO || ''';'

               INTO V_SQL  FROM DUAL;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (V_SQL);

  END LOOP
```

Inside the dynamic query, in this part `"SET  TARGET = ' || VC2.OBJETIVO  || '"` the value `VC2.OBJETIVO` is a `Number` type, and it's replaced like "62481,76". In other words, this comma is making the command wrong and doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to replace the "," for "."?

Thank you very much! (:

Comment: What is datatype of OBJETIVO  ?

Comment: Then am not sure why it would return the number as formatted value.

Comment: You're not sure why it's returning like it is or why I wanna do what I wanna do?

Comment: What is going wrong? Is it reporting an error? Or you are not getting desired result ?

Comment: @Cybernate - it is returning the number as a formatted value because it has to be converted to a string to append to the SQL. Really not the way to go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't build your query by appending strings. You leave yourself open to lots of bugs and vulnerabilities, first of all SQL injection. The need to use dynamic queries doesn't justify not using bind variables. If you really need to use dynamic queries (it is not clear from your example why static update wouldn't work?!), do this instead:

```
FOR vc2 IN (...) LOOP
   v_sql := 
       'BEGIN
            V_UPD NUMBER := 0;

            SELECT (SELECT ID_TIPO_TERR  
              FROM ZREPORTYTD_TMP 
             WHERE AUDITORIA = :p1
               AND TERRITORIO = :p2
               AND PRODUTO = :p3) 
              INTO V_UPD FROM DUAL;

            UPDATE ZReportYTD_TMP
               SET TARGET = :p4
             WHERE AUDITORIA = :p5
               AND TERRITORIO = :p6
               AND PRODUTO = :p7;
        END';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING VC2.AUDITORIA, VC2.NOME, VC2.PRODUTO, 
                                 VC2.OBJETIVO, VC2.AUDITORIA, VC2.NOME, 
                                 VC2.PRODUTO;
END LOOP;
```

Oracle will correctly bind with the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I'll try using this approach.

Comment: Fields like Auditoria and Territorio that are of varchar2 type do not need to be put inside ' '?

Comment: @dev_gabriel: nope, this is the beauty of letting Oracle do the binding :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to use dynamic SQL at all.

Why not something like:

```
FOR VC2 IN (SELECT C.OBJETIVO,
                C.AUDITORIA ,
                C.NOME, 
                C.PRODUTO
           FROM CALCULO C) LOOP

    v_upd := 0;

    SELECT
        ID_TIPO_TERR
    into
        v_UPD
    FROM
        ZREPORTYTD_TMP 
    WHERE
        AUDITORIA = VC2.AUDITORIA
    AND TERRITORIO = VC2.NOME
    AND PRODUTO = VC2.PRODUTO;

    -- is v_upd used anywhere?

    UPDATE
        ZReportYTD_TMP
    SET
        TARGET = VC2.OBJETIVO
    WHERE
        AUDITORIA = VC2.AUDITORIA
    AND TERRITORIO = VC2.NOME
    AND PRODUTO = VC2.PRODUTO;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, but there's a really need to use it dynamic. I just haven't explained it correctly and didn't paste the full code. Thanks for helping, but Vincent's approach already solved my problem (:

Answer (score 0):

I am using Oracle 11g , last couple of day I was facing problem of
execute dynamic query in oracle procedure. I did search lots off.
finally i have got solution .

```
-- In blow procedure we pass multiple argument at run time 
-- We need reference cursor for dynamic query execution
create or replace  PROCEDURE FETCH_REPORT1_NEW(IPID IN number ,CAID IN number,
ZOID IN  number,CLID IN number,SDATE VARCHAR2 , EDATE
VARCHAR2,OUT_VALUE OUT VARCHAR2)

IS

  l_sql varchar(200);   TYPE cursor_ref IS REF CURSOR;   c1
cursor_ref;

  UZID transaction_data.zone_id%TYPE;   OUTAGE_MINS
transaction_data.durationmin%TYPE;

BEGIN

    l_sql := 'select  Avg (durationmin) , zone_id ,
     from transaction_data where  alarm_id in (1,21,26,20) and  zone_id not in(5)';

      IF IPID>0 THEN  

       l_sql := l_sql||' and  IP_ID = '||IPID;

      END IF;         


        l_sql := l_sql||' group by (zone_id)';
       open c1 for l_sql;

          loop
              fetch c1 into OUTAGE_MINS,UZID;

                       dbms_output.put_line(OUTAGE_MINS||UZID);

              exit when c1%notfound;

          end loop;
     close c1; 
    END;
```