# select statement based on table content

Tags: oracle

I have `code_table` which contain the below columns:

```
- ID
- FIELD_NAME
- TABLE_NAME
- WHERE_CONDITION
```

now, I need to write select statement that return table contain 2 columns, the first column is code_table.ID, and the other column is the result of  the below select statement

```
select code_table.FIELD_NAME 
from code_table.TABLE_NAME 
where code_table.WHERE_CONDITION = 1;
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pl/sql - Using a dynamic query inside a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007725/pl-sql-using-a-dynamic-query-inside-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: It's totally different, here I need to use the table content in the select statement

Comment: You need a dynamic query. Use a query to bring the fields content and build a query string. Then execute the query string.

Comment: but even the table name which I have to select from it I need to take it from code_table

Comment: No problem, you include the table_name dynamic on the string query .

Comment: how can I do that ?\

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15335291/3470178) see how he create the string and the use it for open a cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using anonymous block. Hope this helps

```
DECLARE
    cursor cur_code_tab is
    select id,field_name,table_name,where_condition from code_table;
    sql_query varchar2(500);
BEGIN
    for i in cur_code_tab loop
        sql_query:='select '''||i.id||''','||i.field_name||' from '||i.table_name||' where '||i.where_condition=1;
        execute immediate(sql_query);
    end loop;
END;
```